# .NET 6 - Entity Framework Core migrations seed from SQL scripts

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core application with Entity Framework migrations. I am seeding the database in `OnModelCreating()`, like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasData(
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Peter", idDepartment = 3 },
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Rose", idDepartment = 5 },
    ...
);
```

But for some tables, I have SQL scripts that I want to run instead.

How can I run these scripts in `OnModelCreating()`? The SQL scripts are stored in some `.sql` files.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom empty migration and copypaste your scripts queries directly into that migration. With new C# 11 **raw string literals** feature it would be quite simply (literaly copy and paste) to do.

Something like that:

```
public partial class PureSqlMigration : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        var sql =
            $"""
            update dbo.Folders set FullPath = 'Creating Digital Images - EDIT' where FolderId = 1
        """;
        migrationBuilder.Sql(sql);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Then run it. Don't forget about rollback actions if you need them.
Hope it will help.

Answer (score -2):

You could try doing something like this(It's meant to be DbContext).Emloyees(or however your table is called).FromSqlRaw. Or look better here: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql

Comment: this can be used for SELECT statement. what it has to do with seeding your database?

Comment: Actually didnt know that, have used it for select statement thought i would work for modification commands as well. Thanks for the information!